# Creating List<Integer> with all same values in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a List of length 500, all indices initialized to 1000. Then, I would like to set some of these indices to new values. I tried two ways, but get problems and/or errors:

First:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 0;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    list.add(i, 1000);
}
list.set(a, b);
```

If I look at the first ten indices, instead of getting 1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, I get 1000, 1001, 1002 ,3 ,1004 ,1005 ,1006 ,1007 ,1008 ,1009

Second:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 0;
List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(500, 1000);
list.set(a, b);
```

I get an error: java.lang.UnsupoprtedOperationException at the line list.set(a, b)

Comment: Your first code fragment works properly for me.

Comment: *"If I look at the first ten indices, instead of getting 1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, I get 1000, 1001, 1002 ,3 ,1004 ,1005 ,1006 ,1007 ,1008 ,1009"* Not with the code you've quoted. The code you've quoted (the first block) works. (You could just use `list.add(1000)` rather than `list.add(i, 1000)`, but both work.) If you're seeing a problem, it's with code you haven't quoted (perhaps the code looking at the list later.

Comment: Hlo.. index values seems 0 to 499.. pls verify it

Comment: Sorry, I see what I did wrong. I did System.out.println(i + list.get(i)); in a for loop to see what the first ten values were. So I was adding one each time because i is incrementing :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Collection#nCopies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29) creates an *immutable* list, so you cannot use `set` on it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    list.add(i, 1000);
}
```

In this usage of [List#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29), you are adding a number not at the end of the list, but to a specified position.

Try this to just fill the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    list.add(1000);
}
```

(As others have pointed out, this does not seem to make a difference in this particular case, though).

You can combine both methods to

```
list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(500, 1000));
```

Comment: Using `list.add(i, 1000)` and `list.add(1000)` behave identically when `i == list.size()`.

Comment: @TedHopp: True. So in this case, it must be something else we are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i compiled your code and printed the output.It is showing correct result.Just check how you are printing the list.Use:-

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. I was using System.out.println(i + list.get(i))!